How to avoid race conditions when calling a function from a deferred script tag
I want to avoid race conditions when calling a function from a deferred script tag. Notice that the script1 has the defer tag meaning that I want to be fully loaded before any other scripts load. So that the myFunction is always called and only after it is defined in the script1
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <script defer src="script1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       window.onload = function () {
             myFunction()
        }
    </script>
<body>
</html>

I'm still getting the following error Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined in some cases. Generally it works but sometimes it doesn't. My thoughts are that the defer tag is not working as expected but I'm not sure about it.

What about removing the defer attribute, and moving the script after the script which has the dependency?

Can't modify the scrip1 logic. It just defines some functions. I want to use them when the file is fully loaded

evolutionbox isn't suggesting you modify its logic; just change where it's being called and intialized.

why would that help? If I'm not wrong, removing the defer tag will make the DOM to load all the scripts simultaneously causing the race condition

Have you tried it? Removing defer will allow script1 to load when the <head> is loaded; then your window.onload... will run after everything's loaded.

defer will only make that <script> to run after the document is parsed and before DOMContentLoaded event is fired. If it only defines some functions, then there's no need to defer it. Maybe you should defer the <script> which add the load event listener too so that it runs after the other. Else it'll run before the deferred script... Or maybe you can change the load event to DOMContentLoaded event like this: addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', contentEvent => myFunction());. I think this last approach is better.

You can only defer scripts that have source. What's the difference between onload and DOMContentLoaded?

@ResidentZero9999 You're right.. defer can only be applied to elements with a source attribute (src)... My bad.

@ResidentZero9999 The rule for the load event is that it is fired and its handler executed when the download of a source (or all sources if listened on window or document) loads. This can happen even before those are evaluated/parsed because it only waits for the load to finish. The DOMContentLoaded fires after all sources in the document are loaded AND evaluated/parsed, only then the deferred scripts are executed and finally the event handler is executed afterwards. Note that it is still important to maintain things in order (dependencies must be included first).

From MDN's DOMContentLoaded event reference:

The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the HTML document has been completely parsed, and all deferred scripts (<script defer src="…"> and <script type="module">) have downloaded and executed.

From MDN's load event reference:

The load event fires for elements containing a resource when the resource has successfully loaded.

From MDN's  element referente:

This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded event.

This means that a load event will fire regardless of everything else being available to that script and/or event handler. Because the event happens before the document is properly parsed/evaluated.
So, in the Original Poster example, the event handler can execute even before the deferred script is parsed and executed. And it will be like this almost every time (specially in brand new access where there's no cached content).
That being understood, it's best to use the DOMContentLoaded event to handle the document, because it will wait for everything to be loaded and parsed/executed. This way the myFunction function will always be available to the event handler.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <script defer src="script1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       addEventListener
       (
          'DOMContentLoaded', loadEvent =>
          {
             myFunction();
          }
       );
    </script>
<body>
</html>

Note that dependencies should be included before the dependant script when defer is used because the document will load everything, then parse/execute the deferred scripts in order and only then the DOMContentLoaded event will be fired.
Counter example: how everything happens...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <!-- The following script can finish loading before the rest is available -->
    <script src="script1"></script>
    <!-- but can race alongside the following script, that could load and execute first -->
    <script src="script2"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The following script is executed on the fly -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
       // The event handler is fired when everything is loaded, but
       // it not waits for the scripts to be parsed/executed.
       window.onload = function () {
             // If the following function is not available because the
             // script that defines it was not executed, then it will
             // throw the Reference Error.
             myFunction()
        }
    </script>
<body>
<!--
   Everything above can finish loading and execute what's not deferred
   even before `script1` and `script2` finished loading.
-->
</html>

